# Direct print from android application programmatically

Tags: android, printing, printers, android-print-framework

I am planning to develop android application that send data directly to printer. I wonder if there is any possible way to achieve it by "one click" from android app. It's ok to set the printer at very first time, but I don't want to confirm printing every time (it is really annoying to confirm the same printer every time).

Or

Is there any built-in API in android (eg. from HP or Dell) that can connect directly to printer so that I can print directly from app without user confirmation ?

Comment: Why you think is very annoying? An application cannot know if the user has only one printer at his network or if they always want to print to the same printer.
Answering your second question: NO, there's no API from HP that does what you want.

Comment: The user (in my project) has only one printer and he needs to print a lot of documents every day. Actually it is unwanted to confirm printing every time.

Comment: are you fix your problem? my requirement also same things @JakubMichalko

Comment: sadly.. there is no such way how to do it. Lots of mobile phone manufacturer has it's own customization of printing manager and I didn't found anything how to print directly.